# How to render multiple choices field from model

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-models, django-templates

I need to render Product model as follows:

1 -  there are 2 check boxes for gender men/women

- when user checks men only men products appear
- when user check women only women products appear
- when check both or uncheck both all products appear

so I used choices for gender field but how to render that in my template as mentioned above? thanks in advance...

```
GENDER_CHOISES=(
('men', "Men"),
    ('women', "Women"),)
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug  = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price  = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, 
    max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image  = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', 
    null=True, blank=False)
    featured  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active  = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=120,default="women" 
    ,choices=GENDER_CHOISES)
    timestamp= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's for a view that display all the products you can do something like:

Retrieve all the products from the database.
Then you need to use some javascript to hide all the men product if women is selected, and hide women products if the men is selected.

Or the more advanced way will be to use some ajax or create an api to filter the product queryset by the wanted gender each time a checkboxes is selected.

Comment: so you have any javascript snippets do this!!